# How to enable LLAP in Hive 3?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, hadoop3

I installed Hive 3.1.0 on top Hadoop 3.1.1(without using Ambari). How can I enable LLAP feature in Hive.

Answer (score 0):

Configuring LLAP is covered in [Hive Configuration Properties: LLAP section](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Configuration+Properties#ConfigurationProperties-LLAP).  To enable it you need to change `hive.llap.execution.mode`.

The document describes how to set `hive.llap.execution.mode`:

> - Default Value: none
> - Possible Values:
>
>   - none: not tried
>   - map: only map operators are considered for llap
>   - all: every operator is tried; but falls back to no-llap in case of problems
>   - only: same as "all" but stops with an exception if execution is not possible  (as of 2.2.0 with HIVE-15135)
>   - auto: conversion is controlled by hive

For more information about LLAP refer to https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LLAP.

Comment: Hive documentation has no information how to start LLAP containers in Yarn. All it says is "LLAP can be deployed via Slider". Slider project is outdated. 
Hive can create LLAP-app for Yarn. But I can't find how to properly configure and start LLAP-daemon on my Hadoop nodes.

Answer (score 0):

This is a documentation for setting up `LLAP` (Apache Hive Performance Tuning
) in hortonworks:

https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.0/performance-tuning/content/hive_setting_up_llap.html